# Setting application.properties with command line arguments

Tags: spring-boot

I'm tryng to set the file application.properties passing arguments from command line. I'm not an expert of spring boot and I've read some post and article about that, but nothing has been usefull.

I'm passing arguments from STS run configuration. I'm passing to the application two arguments:
--spring.datasource.url =  jdbc:oracle:thin:@SERVERNAME:PORT:DB11G --spring.datasource.username = DBUSERNAME

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"io.swagger.client","com.ids.app.controller","com.ids.app.service"})
@ConfigurationProperties("application.properties")

public class IdsFeApplication implements CommandLineRunner{



    private static final String FEC_CODEX = "A";

    @Autowired
    private static ConfigInfoDB infoDb;

    @Autowired
    private Login fec;




    public static void main(String[] args) {


        SpringApplication.run(IdsFeApplication.class, args);        

    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {

         infoDb.dbInfo();

    fec.token(FEC_CODEX);


    }

}

@Controller
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })

public class ConfigInfoDB {

   @Value(value = "${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String dbConn;

    @Value(value = "${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String dbUser;




    public void dbInfo() {
        System.out.println("dbConn " +dbConn);
        System.out.println(" dbUser "+dbUser);
    }
}
```

This is my application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url = Anonymous
spring.datasource.driver.class=oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.username = Anonymous
```

I would expect to set the application.properties with url and username arguments passed from command line and using these to connect to database. If I use static parameters into the application.properties my application runs well.

[STS Configuration Run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfbRo.png)

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"io.swagger.client","com.ids.app.controller","com.ids.app.service"})

public class IdsFeApplication implements ApplicationRunner{



    private static final String FEC_CODEX = "A";

    @Autowired
    private static ConfigInfoDB infoDb;

    @Autowired
    private Login fec;




    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {

        SpringApplication.run(IdsFeApplication.class, args);        

    }


    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {

        fec.token(FEC_CODEX);
    }

@Controller
public class ConfigInfoDB {

   @Value(value = "${spring.datasource.url}")
    private String dbConn;

    @Value(value = "${spring.datasource.username}")
    private String dbUser;




    public void dbInfo() {
        System.out.println("dbConn " +dbConn);
        System.out.println(" dbUser "+dbUser);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://memorynotfound.com/spring-boot-passing-command-line-arguments-example/ or https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-command-line-arguments

Comment: I've read these articles, but I hadn't solved my problem. I rewrote my code using one of the article you put in the post, but nothing. You can see an image of STS Run Configurations. I'm passing those arguments.

Comment: When I run the application from STS Run configuration, I will obtain "Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured". In tha application.properties spring.datasource.url = Anonymous it is not changed

Answer (score 0):

I test the [code](https://memorynotfound.com/spring-boot-passing-command-line-arguments-example/) and it works for me, so I will post my code snippets.

This is my properties file:

```
person.name=anonymous
```

Now the main class:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

And the controller looks like:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @Value("${person.name}")
    private String name;

    @GetMapping
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello, " + name + "!";
    }
}
```

And if you build the application with `mvn clean install` you can execute the jar archive with:

```
java -jar demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --person.name=flaxel
```

At the end you can browse to this URL: http://localhost:8080/

Comment: I did the same example and I got your same result, but when I pass address url  from command line the application doesn't connect to db. In the application.properties I wrote:``` spring.datasource.url = Anonymous```.